# Difference between numbers on a string

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
 numbers <- c("25", "22|9", "2|5", "23|7" , "25|15")
```

I need to find the difference between numbers on the left and right of "|"

The result should be

```
c(25, 13, -3, 16, 10)
```

Comment: Show some effort, look into `strsplit` function...

Comment: upvoted on the basis of the enthusiastic response from the "community".

Answer (score 4):

If you ever told me I'll be using `eval(parse())`, I would have laughed my ass off, yet here it is.

```
numbers <- c("25", "22|9", "2|5", "23|7" , "25|15")
numbers <- gsub("\\|", "-", numbers)
sapply(numbers, FUN = function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))

   25  22-9   2-5  23-7 25-15 
   25    13    -3    16    10
```

That being said:

```
> require(fortunes)
> fortune("parse")

Personally I have never regretted trying not to underestimate my own future stupidity.
   -- Greg Snow (explaining why eval(parse(...)) is often suboptimal, answering a question triggered by the infamous fortune(106))
      R-help (January 2007)
```

Comment: @Roland I'm off to run the test :-)

Comment: @Roman Luštrik thanks for the answer.  I like your answer, but I am accepting the faster one.

Comment: @user3948526 As you should, do not be swayed by the dark lord of `eval(parse(x))`. :)

Answer (score 3):

Aaaaannd the winner:

```
numin <- rep(c("25", "22|9", "2|5", "23|7" , "25|15"),1000)
roman <- function(numbers){
numbers <- gsub("\\|", "-", numbers)
sapply(numbers, FUN = function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
}

akrun<-function(numbers){
with(read.table(text=gsub("^(\\d+)$", "\\1|0", numbers), sep="|", header=FALSE), V1-V2)
}
arenburg<-function(numbers){
temp <- strsplit(numbers, "[|]")
sapply(temp, function(x) {x <- as.numeric(x) ; if(!is.na(x[2])) x[1] - x[2] else x[1]} )
}
    aren2 <-function(numbers){
as.numeric(gsubfn("([0-9]+)[|]([0-9]+)", ~ as.numeric(x) - as.numeric(y), numbers))
}

microbenchmark(roman(numin),akrun(numin),arenburg(numin),aren2(numin),times=3)
Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min         lq     median        uq
    roman(numin)  306.9893  325.70831  344.42732  352.0125
    akrun(numin)   17.7421   17.94138   18.14065   18.1941
 arenburg(numin)  222.0295  222.91272  223.79597  228.9837
    aren2(numin) 2214.5777 2244.93384 2275.28998 2320.8854
        max neval
  359.59769     3
   18.24756     3
  234.17140     3
 2366.48072     3
```

UPDATE:  the above was on Windows7-64, R3.1.1  I ran again on OSX SnowLeopard, Intel Core2 Duo, R3.1.0, and got

```
Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min         lq     median         uq       max neval
    roman(numin)  604.2358  605.65310  607.07037  617.16463  627.2589     3
    akrun(numin)  103.3000  103.56248  103.82494  104.89133  105.9577     3
 arenburg(numin)   36.8553   39.40521   41.95512   41.95746   41.9598     3
    aren2(numin) 2976.1608 3052.62308 3129.08530 3206.96755 3284.8498     3
```

So it ain't all that clear how/why akrun vs. arenburg works out.

Comment: Why didn't you benchmark the `gsubfn` (my first answer) too?

Comment: Okay, in @akrun's answer subtraction is vectorized. That's why it is faster than parsing/evaluating each expression.

Comment: @DavidArenburg just because I was too lazy to install the package :-(.  I'll try to get to an update.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Don't sell your `strsplit` answer short. I think Carl's benchmarks are majorly off...

Comment: @AnandaMahto What can I do to make them more accurate?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, run them again? I'm getting comparable values, and David's approach can easily be made a little faster with a few small tweaks.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  see my latest test set.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft Using R 3.1.0 on a linux platform, I get `roman(numin) 313.24914; akrun(numin) 7.51102; arenburg(numin) 21.66738; aren2(numin) 2194.34966` using the same code.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `gsubfn` package

```
library(gsubfn)
as.numeric(gsubfn("([0-9]+)[|]([0-9]+)", ~ as.numeric(x) - as.numeric(y), numbers))
## [1] 25 13 -3 16 10
```

Or a `strsplit` solution

```
temp <- strsplit(numbers, "[|]")
sapply(temp, function(x) {x <- as.numeric(x) ; if(!is.na(x[2])) x[1] - x[2] else x[1]})
## [1] 25 13 -3 16 10
```